Can a Feynman graph be an empty set?
I was reading the section about Feynman graphs from the book Renormalization - An Introduction and this question arose. To set the notations, let $p \in \mathbb{N}_{+}$ and, for each $k \in \{1,...,p\}$, let $m_{k} \in \mathbb{N}_{+}$. Define the set:
$$B_{0} = \{(k,i_{k}): \hspace{0.1cm} \mbox{$k \in \{1,...,p\}$ and $i_{k} \in \{1,...,m_{k}\}$}\}$$
The next step is to define a partial order in $B_{0}$ by setting $(k, i) < (l,j)$ iff $k < l$. For each $\emptyset \neq B \subset B_{0}$, we introduce:
$$L_{0}(B) = \{(b,b') \in B\times B: \hspace{0.1cm} b < b'\}$$
Finally, also for $\emptyset \neq B \subset B$, we define $\mathcal{L}(B)$ to be the set of all sets $L$ of the form:
$$L = \{(b,b') \in L_{0}(B): \hspace{0.1cm} \mbox{$\pi_{1}|_{L}(b,b')$ and $\pi_{2}|_{L}(b,b')$ are both bijections}\}$$
The notation is as follows. $\pi_{i}|_{L}(b,b')$ denotes the projection into the $i$-th entry, $i=1,2$. More precisely, $\pi_{1}|_{L}(b,b') = b$ and $\pi_{2}|_{L}(b,b') = b'$. In my opinion, this condition is a bit confusing and this is probably the heart of the issue. It is not clear what is the range of $\pi_{i}|_{L}$ where these maps are bijections, but I assume that the condition means that every $b \in B$ appears once either as a first or second entry of $(b,b') \in L$. In any case, the definition of a Feynman graph is:
Definition: Let $E \subset B_{0}$. A Feynman graph is an element of $\mathcal{L}(B_{0}\setminus E)$.
Because I was a bit confused with these definitions, I decided to work out some explicit examples. Suppose $p=2$ and $m_{1} = m_{2} = 2$, so that $B_{0} = \{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$. Let $E = \{(1,1)\}$. Then, $B_{0}\setminus E = \{(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$ and $L_{0}(B_{0}\setminus E) = \{((1,2),(2,1)),((1,2),(2,2))\}$. Now, the Feynman graphs are elements of $\mathcal{L}(B_{0}\setminus E)$ and these are subsets of $L_{0}(B_{0}\setminus E)$ where each element occurs only once in some entry. Because of the partial ordering condition, we see that for the above case $L_{0}(B_{0}\setminus E)$, it is impossible to form such a set because we would have to repeat the entry $(1,2)$ in order to include both $(2,1)$ and $(2,2)$ in the second entry. Hence, $\mathcal{L}(B_{0}\setminus E) = \emptyset$. In particular, this will happen everytime that $E$ removes more points of the form $(k,\cdot)$ than points $(l,\cdot)$, for $k \neq l$.
So, my question is: is my understanding of the definition wrong or are there simply many empty Feynman graphs, according to this definition? And, if so, what is the interpretation of an empty Feynman graph? Is it just a graph that does not contribute to the expansion of the underlying physical object?

I cannot parse this definition (it lacks the structure I associate with Feynman graphs); you might find it of interest to look at an alternative definition in terms of rooted maps: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/302255803.pdf

I don't understand: if a Feynman graph is an element of $\mathcal{L}$, and $\mathcal{L}=\emptyset$, how does that mean that a Feynman graph is empty? As I read it, it simply means that there are no Feynman graphs.

@gmvh fair point. I should had written "set of Feynman graphs" instead.

In any case, it is still intriguing because a lot of these sets are empty.

SInce I, much like Carlo Beenakker, cannot really parse this definition, which appears to bear no clear relation to what I would call a Feynman graph, I cannot tell what is the real reason why many of these sets appear to be empty. On the other hand, for Feynman graphs as conventionally understood in a QFT context, there will be plenty of set of Feynman graphs that are empty (e.g. any set of graphs with an odd number of external legs in a theory with only even-order interactions).

@gmvh a piece of information which might be useful: In the post, elements of $B_{0}$ are these external legs and $k\in {1,...,p}$ indexes the vertices. Then $L_{0}(B)$ are lines connecting these external vertices. The idea of the definition of the Feynman graph is to associate some external legs to fields and then "connect" the remaining ones.

Well, then obviously there are many situations where one can't form a Feynman graph with a given number of legs and vertices of a given adicity.

Consolidating from comments:

The definitions given in the question are a bit unusual, so it is not straightforward to interpret them.

However, best as I understand the question, it is not about whether a Feynman graph can be empty, but about whether the set of Feynman graphs for a given theory (given by the $m_k$), order (given by $p$) and set of external legs (given by $E$) can be empty.

The answer to that question is a resounding "yes", since e.g. there are no Feynman graphs with an odd number of external legs in $\phi^4$ theory, or more generally no Feynman graphs contributing to an odd-$n$ $n$-point function in a theory with only even-order vertices due to symmetry considerations (even vs odd under $\phi\mapsto-\phi$).


The example given appears to be (best as I can interpret it) about a theory with a quadratic interaction (that's already a bit unusual, since this would normally be treated as a mass instead), for which you are looking at the second-order contribution to the one-point function (one external leg). This is indeed empty, as explained above, since one is odd and two is even.
